# calling a JavaScript function with HTMLUnit

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I'm trying to call the function `showPage('3');` of [this page](http://www.visittrentino.it/it/cosa_fare/eventi/risultati?minEventDate=09012014&maxEventDate=31012014&tp=searchForm.thismonth&ltp=gennaio), for use the page source code after. I tried to do with `htmlUnit` like so:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.visittrentino.it/it/cosa_fare/eventi/risultati?minEventDate=09012014&maxEventDate=31012014&tp=searchForm.thismonth&ltp=gennaio");

String javaScriptCode = "showPage('3');";

ScriptResult result = page.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode);
result.getJavaScriptResult();
System.out.println("result: "+ result);
```

But it's not working.
It prints out:

> result: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Undefined@a303147

and other 10000 warnings. What am I doing wrong? I need to change the page of this site for do some crawling on the source code. Is there another way (and maybe more easier) for calling jsp-function from Java code and then navigate in the source of the page? 
Thank you for any help, have a nice day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You print the ScriptResult object not the content of the page,change the SOP code to result.getNewPage()

Comment: welcome and if the answer work for u then select it as correct answer

Comment: Object result = page.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode).getJavaScriptResult();
     page.getPage(); System.out.println("result: "+result+"\n"+page.getPage());
result is a object and dont have .getNewPage() or something so method...

Comment: ScriptResult result = page.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode); then you  can print by using result.getNewPage().

Comment: sry man, now i understand you! ty for the help have a nice day!

Comment: `ScriptResult.getNewPage()` was removed in a recent version. The change suggests to use `page.getWebClient().getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage()` instead: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/commit/120d9040184cecea08073ccacb3383848a7f9746#diff-32b86263e0cea174da9b8ceb6f9482fc