# Navigating through a website by pressing on JS buttons using HTMLUnit

Tags: java, http-post, htmlunit

***I'm attempting to press a Javascript Button on a webpage using `HTMLUnit 2.36` which navigates to another page, and so on...***:

```
ScriptResult result = page.executeJavaScript("__doPostBack('LinkBtn_thebutton','')");
Page page = result.getNewPage();
```

I've attempted to use the code above which causes the following error, supposedly because `getNewPage()` is no longer supported:

```
The method GetNewPage() is undefined for type ScriptResult
```

I've also attempted to add a cast with `getJavaScriptResult()` as shown below with no luck:

```
HtmlPage page1 = (HtmlPage) result.getJavaScriptResult();
```

Causing the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Undefined cannot be cast to class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to cast the `result.getJavaScriptResult();`, treat it like a void. If your page is going to be redirected, make sure that redirecting is enabled: `webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);`

Comment: Okay, If that is the case how am I then meant to then navigate to yet another web page and continue doing so?

Comment: you need to wait for the javascript to be done, for example with `webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100);`. Or make your own while loop: `While(!page.contains("element")) webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100);`

Comment: Does the result not need to be set as type `HtmlPage` in order to do so?

Comment: Alright, How can I then view the contents of the `result`?

Comment: you just access the page : `page.asXml()` or `page.asText()`

Comment: Ah okay, I was thinking about it wrongly :) I'm now getting the following error: `Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[value] attributeValue=[View Timetable]` - [Source](https://i.gyazo.com/b79ccb17a33d1ab58fbf384c1c19409c.png) | [Updated Coded](https://hastebin.com/nodukehuhe.cs) - Is it possible the code you suggested is not working?

Comment: make it a condition to find that element, and loop with `webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100);` until its positive

Comment: Test your javascript code in your native browser. If its working, change the browserVersion. HtmlUnit and JS is a pain